# Unexpected token < From a Style Tag

Tags: javascript

I keep getting "Unexpected token <" because of this script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.pathname + window.location.search = '/search/?q=label:Web-Design|label:Graphic-Design|label:Identity-Design|label:Brand-Design') {
      document.write (<style type="text/css">#HTML25, #HTML23, #HTML22, #HTML24 { display:block; }</style>);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I don't understand why it's throwing that error. I have been researching for about 2 hours now. I tried adding CDATA tags, I tried using entity names instead of characters, I made sure there was no whitespace within the document.write, etc, etc. Why won't it work? I thought document.write supported HTML entities?

**EDIT**: I changed the `=` operator to `==` . I also added single quotes, but then when I submitted to Blogger I got the XML error: "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup" so I changed the HTML Characters to HTML Names and resubmitted. I am still getting the "unexpected token" < error...

**UPDATE** I have updated the script to this, but still get the exact same error:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if ((window.location.pathname + window.location.search) === '/search/?q=label:Web-Design|label:Graphic-Design|label:Identity-Design|label:Brand-Design') {
         document.write ('<style type="text/css">#HTML25, #HTML23, #HTML22, #HTML24 { display:block; }</style>');
      }
    });
  ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Try this: document.write ('<style type="text/css">#HTML25, #HTML23, #HTML22, #HTML24 { display:block; }</style>');
watch the qoutes added

Comment: change the equal operator `=` to `==`

Comment: your ide should have caught this, or if you are not using an ide, run it through an online lint and it should give you a listing of your errors http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least you have to add a single quote around your string ...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ((window.location.pathname + window.location.search) === '/search/?q=label:Web-Design|label:Graphic-Design|label:Identity-Design|label:Brand-Design') {
       // add the style to your head
       $('head').append(String.fromCharCode(60) + 'style type="text/css">#HTML25, #HTML23, #HTML22, #HTML24 { display:block; }' + String.fromCharCode(60) + '/style>');
       // or decide to individually show the divs with jquery selectors
       $('div#HTML25').css('display', 'block');

    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: I have added the single quotes, can't believe I missed that. However, now I get XML error when I submit to Blogger "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup". Any ideas?

Comment: I added the CDATA tags, but I'm still getting a "Unexpected token <".

Comment: I even went ahead and copy & pasted your code instead, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blogger but I assume you are sure that you can submit a javascript block? In other words: it is not complaining about the < of your script tag? I updated again with a fromCharCode construct

Comment: It is a template edit. I added this script just before the closing HEAD tag. I have added other scripts without a problem. You can view the issue live here: http://www.xarpixels.com/search/?q=label:Web-Design|label:Graphic-Design|label:Identity-Design|label:Brand-Design

Comment: no it doesn't work. There should be elements visible(display:block) just under the menu.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36682/discussion-between-rene-and-xarcell)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (window.location.pathname + window.location.search == '/search/?q=label:Web-Design|label:Graphic-Design|label:Identity-Design|label:Brand-Design') {

            document.write("<style type='text/css'>#HTML25, #HTML23, #HTML22, #HTML24 { display:block; }</style>");
    }                     
});
```